# Why am I getting this warning? "Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in url code"

Tags: php

When you insert your website link, it will show you your site's robots.txt but will give error on top:

> Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/hjlhvqyy/public_html/fastseoindia/klib/k_functions_http.php on line 101
>
> Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/hjlhvqyy/public_html/fastseoindia/klib/k_functions_http.php on line 105

My code:

```
if ((eregi( "^http://",$url))) //line 101 
{
    $url = substr($url,7);
}
elseif((eregi( "^https://",$url))) //line 105
{
    $url = substr($url,8);
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Stop using that function, maybe?

Comment: Look at the "Related" column here on the right

Comment: Read this: http://us3.php.net/eregi

Comment: [deprecated](https://www.google.com/#q=deprecated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the [`eregi()`](https://www.php.net/eregi) function is deprecated. Use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) OR [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) instead.

Comment: The question is a dupe of tens of other questions, I believe people should stop answering or there'll be no point in closing as duplicate

Comment: thankz friend..... for help....

Comment: @saiyyedfardeen your welcome friend

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you move over to preg_match, unless you have a good reason not to.

It would have to be a pretty darn good reason though.

Aside from that, this doesn't even really need to use a regular expression to achieve your goal.

you could quite easily use a if(0 === strpos()) to check for the existance of either, and then clear it out.  EG

```
if(0 === strpos('http://', $str))
{
  $str = str_replace('http://', $str);
}else if(0 === strpos('https://', $str))
{
 $str = str_replace('https://', $str);
}
```

Comment: The question is a dupe of tens of other questions, I believe people should stop answering or there'll be no point in closing as duplicate